# CakePHP E-mail with GMAIL

Tags: php, email, cakephp, gmail, cakephp-1.3

I have the following code:

```
$this->Email->smtpOptions = Configure::read("Email.smtpOptions");
$this->Email->delivery = 'smtp';
$this->Email->sendAs = "html";
$this->Email->from = $_POST['name'] . ' <' . $_POST['email'] . '>';
$this->Email->replyTo = $_POST['name'] . ' <' . $_POST['email'] . '>';
$this->Email->to = CONTACTEMAIL;
$this->Email->subject = WEBSITEURL . " - Contact Form";
$this->Email->template = "contactform";
```

The only tiny problem with this is that when viewing who actually sent the e-mail, the e-mail address is the one I am using to connect with the GMAIL SMTP, the name is actually fine.  Thanks to the replyTo attribute, when clicking reply, the To address is fine but I really would like to know if it's even possible to have the From address as I set it.?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the sender address to gmail and verify it:

http://www.askdavetaylor.com/configure_google_gmail_to_have_a_different_sender.html has a nice guide on how to do so.